# Refactoring advice/ideas needed

Tags: .net-3.5, c#-3.0, console-application

I was looking for ideas on improving the following code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    bool validInput1 = false;
    string input1 = string.Empty;
    bool validInput2 = false;
    string input2 = string.Empty;

    bool validFilePath = false;
    string filePath = string.Empty;


    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Import process started.");

        while (!validFilePath)
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter the full path to the file you would like to import: ");
            filePath = Console.ReadLine().Replace("\"","");
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
                validFilePath = true;
        }

        while (!validInput1)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a valid eventID the import file: ");
            input1 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (ValidEventID(input1.Trim().Length))
                validInput1 = true;
        }

        while (!validInput2)
        {
            Console.Write("Enter a valid import type code: ");
            input2 = Console.ReadLine();
            if (input2.Trim().ToUpper() == "EX" || input2.Trim().ToUpper() == "EL")
                validInput2 = true;
        }


        var records = Utilities.ParseCSV(filePath);
        var import = new Import
        {
            EventId = input1,
            ImportType = input2
        };


        import.ImportEventDates(records);

        Console.WriteLine("Import process completed.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Error encountered");
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd write a simple method to retrieve and validate user input :

```
public static string PromptUntilValid(string promptText, Func<string, bool> validationPredicate)
{
    string input;
    do
    {
        Console.Write(promptText);
        input = Console.ReadLine();
    } while (!validationPredicate(input))
    return input;
}
```

This would allow your code to be refactored as follows :

```
    ...

    filePath = PromptUntilValid(
        "Please enter the full path to the file you would like to import: ",
        s => File.Exists(s));

    input1 = PromptUntilValid(
        "Enter a valid eventID the import file: ",
        s => ValidEventID(s.Trim().Length));

    input2 = PromptUntilValid(
        "Enter a valid import type code: ",
        s => s.Trim().ToUpper() == "EX" || s.Trim().ToUpper() == "EL");

    ...
```

Comment: Thanks! This does look alot nicer than the multiple while loops. =D

Comment: This is also much better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

You could try taking the while loops out and putting them each in their own functions which return the valid filepath and inputs and throw exceptions if they're caught.  For example:

```
public string FindValidFilepath()
{
    string filePath = string.Empty
    try{
        while (!validFilePath)
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter the full path to the file you would like to import: ");
            filePath = Console.ReadLine().Replace("\"","");
            if (File.Exists(filePath))
                validFilePath = true;
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw;
    }
    return filePath
}
```

and call it from the Main function.  Other things you can do which will reduce errors if you have to add code is to put curly braces, {, around the code within your If statements.  While not having them is syntactically legal, it will keep an error from popping up later.  I have been bitten by a mistake like that in the past.

EDIT: The rethrowing of this exception is so that the original Try-Catch block can stay in place. Also, I've learned that "throw ex" loses the stack trace but simply "throw" keeps it.  I've corrected this issue.

EDIT 2: One more thing I thought of, try catching specific exceptions and outputting a specific error explaining what went wrong to the user so they can better understand the problem. Most users don't understand a stack trace unless outputting the stack trace is a requirement.

Also, please excuse any small syntax errors, I'm more familiar with Java than C#.

Comment: -1 for `catch (Exception ex) {throw ex;}` that will lose the stack trace. Just don't catch the exception if you're not going to fix the problem.

Comment: Indeed `throw` is better than `throw ex`, but the try/catch block is still useless if you're not doing anything in the catch block... Just let the exception bubble up the stack and be caught by the next try/catch block

Comment: Oy, my Java familiarity is biting me again. In Java you have to specify when an exception is going to be thrown. I'll leave it since it's still valid code and something else may be put in there if they want.

Comment: "In Java you have to specify when an exception is going to be thrown" : that's the one thing I like in Java that C# doesn't have...